# Protection of programs and databases

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Now the desktop application is created.. Connect to mysql database (server) .. This application does many things for users like (Create new user..Change password...) Now there is a command line start connection and contains This line on the connection information through IP - User - Password - Port
like this

'Test.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.1.100;user id=root;Password=123456789;persist security info=True;database=account'

But the problem is that a lot of people said that this app is too risky
Because this can any hacker to decrypt the application and get the connection information of the database
Now.. is there any way to protect or any other ways to make the connection secure

Comment: Your question is way to broad. If you want to learn about security then do some research on security. Post here when you have a specific question.

Answer (score -1):

Don't hardcode credentials, let users login to the target server instead. This way you can control who can have access to the database. Also avoid giving root access to the users, but create individual accounts i.e. per department.